# ROS2 - colcon build fails to find configuration file provided by "ament_cmake"

Tags: ros, ros2, colcon, windows10

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm currently doing the ROS2 tutorial on Windows 10: "Creating a workspace" (https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Workspace/Creating-A-Workspace/#ros2workspace) using Ros2_foxy. So I'm a beginner.

However, upon trying to build the workspace with colcon, I get the following error:

```
PS C:\dev_ws\ colcon build - -merge -install 
Starting turtlesim 
--- stderr: turtlesim 
CMake Error at CMakeLists . txt:12 (find_package): 

By not providing "Findament_cmake.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "ament_cmake", but CMake did not find one. 

Could not find a package configuration file provided by " ament_cmake" with any of the following names: 

ament_cmakeConfig.cmake
ament_cmake-config.cmake 

Add the installation prefix of "ament_cmake" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH" or set "ament_cmake DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files. If "ament_cmake" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
```

It would seem that I need to change my PATH to include the ament files, but I have no idea where to find them. I reinstalled CMake using Chocolatey, but that didn't solve it. And of course I'm sourcing ROS in my terminal.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/356508/ros2---colcon-build-fails-to-find-configuration-file-provided-by-%22ament_cmake%22/) by [Tortelenny](https://answers.ros.org/users/56272/tortelenny/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-07-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-07-07**:
Why did you delete your question?

If you have solved it, please post an answer yourself.

That way we can help future users to avoid this.

**Comment by [Tortelenny](https://answers.ros.org/users/56272/tortelenny/) on 2020-07-07**:
I deleted it because I have no clue what solved it. I came back into work the next day, tried it again, and it worked. I really don't know why, as I already rebooted the day before as well...
I didn't want others wasting their time on my question, so I thought deleting it would be more appropriate in this case. Should I keep it open?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-07-07**:
I would still suggest you post that as an answer.

It's not a good one, but it is *an* answer, and it did 'solve' your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Had this problem in ubuntu, I missed environment setup so
**"source /opt/ros//setup.bash"** helped.

In windows - call C:\dev\ros2_foxy\install\local_setup.bat might help (not tried though)

---

Originally posted by [Akarsh](https://answers.ros.org/users/30107/akarsh/) with karma: 76 on 2020-11-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Morris](https://answers.ros.org/users/24538/morris/) on 2022-07-25**:
Yes, sourcing the underlay is that is needed.